# Is there an R function to add content to an already existing list?

Tags: r

I am a newbie on R. I am trying to create a list within 2 functions. The first one is the extraction function, it takes the data and creates a list with it. The second one is the process one, it calculates some values and I need them to be together in the first list. How do I do that ?

```
myfun <- function(data,number_meta) { #extraction function
  OR  <- data$`Odds Ratio`[data$`Identification number`==number_meta]
  SE  <- ((log(data$`Upper limit`) - (log(data$`Lower limit`))) / 3.92)[data$`Identification number`==number_meta]
  res <- metagen(TE=log(OR),seTE=SE,sm="OR")

  tableau = cbind(OR, SE)
  LIST = list(tableau, res)

  return(LIST)
}

myfun(data,number_meta) 
number_meta = c(1:33)
i = c(1:33)
number_meta = i
LIST = list()

for (i in 1:33) {
  LIST[[i]] = myfun(data, number_meta[i])
}

myfun2 <- function(LIST) { # processing function
  dup_OR <- duplicated(LIST[[i]][[1]][,1])
  dup_SE <- duplicated(LIST[[i]][[1]][,2])

  options(scipen = 999)

  Egger  <- metabias(LIST[[i]][[2]], method.bias = "linreg", k.min = 1)
  Begg   <- metabias(LIST[[i]][[2]], method.bias = "rank",   k.min = 1)
  Result <- c(dup_OR,dup_SE,Egger,Begg)

  return(Result)
}

myfun2(LIST)

for (i in 1:33) {
  LIST[[i]] = c(LIST, list(myfun2(LIST))) ## This one is not working !
}
```

I would like to obtain a final list of 33 items in which I could find inside the different values of res, dup_OR, dup_SE, Egger, Begg. These values varies from the values of res. Thanks for your help

Here is my original script :

```
setwd("U:/Stage M2 Phame")

library(readxl)

library(meta)

data <- read_excel("Tableau_OR.xlsx")

OR <- ((data$`Odds Ratio`[data$`Identification number`==number_meta[i]]))

SE <- (((log(data$`Upper limit`) - (log(data$`Lower limit`)))/3.92)[data$`Identification 
number`==number_meta[i]])

dup_OR <- duplicated(OR)

dup_SE <- duplicated(SE)

options(scipen = 999)

res <- metagen(TE=log(OR),seTE=SE,sm="OR")

Egger <- metabias(res, method.bias = "linreg", k.min = 5)

Begg <- metabias(res, method.bias = "rank", k.min = 5)

Trim <- trimfill(res) 

LIST=list(dup_OR, dup_SE, Egger, Begg, Trim)
```

Sorry for my whole block of text.

Comment: First, can you provide us a code snippet that we can run ourselves? Second, please don't be afraid to use empty lines to enhance readability

Comment: To add a new element to a list just use the `c` operator:  `LIST <- c(LIST, newelement)`

Comment: @RafaelToledo  using the c() operator adds each element of 'newelement' as a separate element of the list, so is not correct. Try `LIST <- c(LIST, mtcars)` vs `LIST[[x]] = mtcars ` as an example.

Comment: Yes, it extends the list. In case `newelement` is a  list, and you want to keep all of its elements in an unique place. Use: `LIST <- c(LIST, list(newelement))`

Comment: Yes...if `newelement` is a list `c()` will bind the to `LIST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (I have taken the liberty of generating a minimal working example):

```
## define a function that appends something to an existing list
appendtolist = function(oldlist, add_element){

    if(class(add_element) == "list"){
        oldlist = c(oldlist, add_element)
    }
    else if(class(add_element) != "list"){
        oldlist[[length(oldlist) + 1]] = add_element
    }
    return(oldlist)
}

## define a test list
firstlist = list("a", c(1:10), "test")

## add content to the first list
newlist = appendtolist(firstlist, c(1:1000))
```

Comment: Great! Watch out: `LIST = c(LIST, newelement)` will give a different result from `LIST[[x]] = newelement`! (See above comment).